# Is there a Philz coffee at SFO airport? Where is it?

Tags: food-and-drink, sfo

I can't see one listed on either the SFO website https://www.flysfo.com/shop-dine-relax/dining or on the Philz site https://www.philzcoffee.com/locations.

A friend tells me there is one and I saw a few people carrying Philz paper cups around after security in the international terminal, but didn't have time to ask where the store was.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but if you don't see one on the airport site or the Philz site, why do you think there might be one?

Comment: Why worry about which coffee is sold, is there so much difference? (I do not drink coffee, I could not care less.)

Comment: In which terminal did you see people with these cups?

Comment: @Willeke: Obviously it's a matter of opinion, but Philz has a special reputation in the Bay Area.  They have a very large number of different varieties of coffee beans to choose from, and brew mainly by the pourover method which gives very different flavors.  I'm sure the good people at [Coffee.SE](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/) would gladly tell you more :-)

Comment: In the international terminal. I've edited the question to include this. Thanks.

Comment: @Gareth Does your friend know if it was the A side or the G side of the international terminal? It's possible that some third-party serves it, but I can't see who that would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Philz does not have a location at the airport.

As best I can tell, none of SFO's vendors brew Philz coffee either. There are a number of Peet's and Starbucks locations, and various other retailers that serve Equator Coffee, Flying Goat Coffee, wherever Joe & The Juice gets its coffee from, and Emporio Rulli roasts their own.

There are Philz locations within six miles from the airport in South San Francisco, San Mateo, and Burlingame.

Answer (score 3):

I got a reply from a message I sent to Philz:

> Thanks for reaching out! Unfortunately, we don't have a coffee shop at
>   SFO and don't have any immediate plans to open one.
>
> Our bagged beans are periodically available for purchase at the Duty
>   Free Shop found in the international terminal. This may be what your
>   friend was referring to which may have caused the confusion.

Seems I must have been mistaken.